# SQL frequency calculation

Tags: sql, frequency, calculation

I have a dataset where I need to calculate the frequency that a counter occurs within a given test run and platform. For example, a platform has 4 test runs and 3/4 runs increment a counter (75%).

I have the following view, and need an SQL query to calculate the frequency -

```
TestPlatform | CounterID | Frequency
1.2 | 3 | 75%.
```

The view I've created is like this:
[view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1XIa.png)

The desired result looks something like this:
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJuHB.png)

Any help or sample SQL is much appreciated!!

Comment: Looks like you already have created a view that calculates frequency! Can you be clearer what you actually need?

Comment: Also, what flavor of SQL?